# eval code.js what is this?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

```
(function($filter,ensureSafeMemberName,ensureSafeObject,ensureSafeFunction,getStringValue,ensureSafeAssignContext,ifDefined,plus,text
/*``*/) {
"use strict";
var fn=function(s,l,a,i){var v5,v6=l&&('filteredOrders' in l);if(!(v6)){if(s){v5=s.filteredOrders;}}else{v5=l.filteredOrders;}return v5;};fn.assign=function(s,v,l){var v0,v1,v2,v3,v4=l&&('filteredOrders' in l);v3=v4?l:s;if(!(v4)){if(s){v2=s.filteredOrders;}}else{v2=l.filteredOrders;}if(v3!=null){v1=v;ensureSafeObject(v3.filteredOrders,text);ensureSafeAssignContext(v3,text);v0=v3.filteredOrders=v1;}return v0;};return fn;
})

(function($filter,ensureSafeMemberName,ensureSafeObject,ensureSafeFunction,getStringValue,ensureSafeAssignContext,ifDefined,plus,text
/*``*/) {
"use strict";
var fn=function(s,l,a,i){var v0,v1,v2,v3=l&&('selectPage' in l),v4,v5,v6=l&&('\u0024event' in l);v2=v3?l:s;if(!(v3)){if(s){v1=s.selectPage;}}else{v1=l.selectPage;}ensureSafeObject(v1,text);if(v1!=null){ensureSafeFunction(v1,text);v4=1;if(!(v6)){if(s){v5=s.$event;}}else{v5=l.$event;}ensureSafeObject(v5,text);v0=ensureSafeObject(v2.selectPage(ensureSafeObject(1,text),ensureSafeObject(v5,text)),text);}else{v0=undefined;}return v0;};return fn;
})
```

Whilst running my MVC project in Visual Studio 2017 professional, it stops at the first "use strict" statement above.  The eval code.js file it belongs to is in the Script Documents folder and has 300lines similar to the above and another 400 with all the contents of inline scripts and js files added.

edit the pointer that stops at the above has a notation 'The process or thread has changed since last step.

What is this file and why would this occur?

Comment: This is uglified. Uglyfying reduces the filesize and therefore makes page loads faster.

Comment: Ok thanks, so if I rebuild this warning/error will go away?

Comment: I dont see any error. `The process or thread has changed since last step.` thats not an error.

Comment: Sorry!  Its however enough to pause execution.  What will I need to do to suppress this?

Comment: I dunno, i dont use visual studio ... Hope someone else can help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all part of microsofts development system and the issue isnt an error.
See further https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/eval-function-javascript